Degree Bounds in Nullstellensatz Proof System
I'll start with some background. Consider the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is a field. Let $\mathcal{F} = \{f_1=0, \ldots, f_m=0\}$ be a set of polynomial constraints and let $V = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ f_1(x)=f_2(x)=\ldots=f_m(x)=0\}$ be the set of common zeros of the polynomials in $\mathcal{F}$. Assume that the Boolean constraints $x_i^2 - x_i =0$ are included in $\mathcal{F}$ for every $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$. A Nullstellensatz refutation of $\mathcal{F}$ is an identity of the form
$$ 1 = \sum_{i=1}^m g_i f_i. $$
where $g_i \in \mathbb{F}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ are polynomials. The degree $d$ of the refutation is defined as $d = \max \{\deg_i g_i f_i\}$.
It is known that whenever $S = \emptyset$, i.e. when the polynomial system $\mathcal{F}$ is infeasible, then there exist such identities.
Here's what I don't understand. Many papers state (claiming it is evident) that the polynomial coefficients $g_i$ can be assumed to be of the degree at most $O(n)$, since these polynomials can be multilinearized using the Boolean constraints $x_i^2 - x_i = 0$. Therefore, the upper bound on the degree of such refutations is $O(n)$. How can I see this?
Moreover, let's relabel the Boolean constraints as $B_1 = x_1^2 - x_1, \ldots, B_n = x_n^2 - x_n$, thus $\mathcal{F} = \{f_1=0, \ldots, f_m=0, B_1=0, \ldots, B_n=0\}$. If $\mathcal{F}$ is infeasible, then there exists a Nullstellensatz refutation
$$1 = \sum g_i f_i + \sum h_i B_i$$
where $g_i, h_i \in \mathbb{F}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$. I can see why we can assume that $g_i$ is multilinear. But why can also $h_i$ be assumed to be multilinear?
(Some) References:

D. Grigoriev, "Tseitin's tautologies and lower bounds for Nullstellensatz proofs," Proceedings 39th Annual Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science (Cat. No.98CB36280), Palo Alto, CA, USA, 1998, pp. 648-652, doi: 10.1109/SFCS.1998.743515.
D. Grigoriev, “Linear lower bound on degrees of Positivstellensatz calculus proofs for the parity,” Theoretical Computer Science, vol. 259, no. 1–2, pp. 613–622, May 2001, doi: 10.1016/S0304-3975(00)00157-2.


As Josh mentions, there is no way around the fact that the degree of the input polynomials $d=\max\{f_i:i\in[m]\}$ can be arbitrarily large, whence so can be the minimal degree of a refutation. However, it is easy to see that once there is any refutation at all (i.e., the $\vec f_i$ have no common $\{0,1\}$ zero), there is one of degree at most $d+n$:
As you already noted in the question, given
$$1=\sum_if_ig_i+\sum_i(x_i^2-x_i)h_i,$$
you may replace each $g_i$ with its multilinearization $M(g_i)$ while retaining the relation
$$1-\sum_if_ig_i\in\sum_i(x_i^2-x_i)\mathbb F[\vec x].$$
This ensures $\deg(g_i)\le n$, thus $\deg(f_ig_i)\le d+n$. Moreover,
$$h=1-\sum_if_ig_i$$
is a polynomial of degree $d+n$ such that $M(h)=0$. Thus, it remains to observe that for any polynomial $h\in\mathbb F[\vec x]$, we can write
$$h-M(h)=\sum_i(x_i^2-x_i)h_i$$
for some $h_i$ such that $\deg\bigl((x_i^2-x_i)h_i\bigr)\le\deg(h)$. E.g., this can be done by successively lowering the degree of each monomial: if $e_i>1$, we have
$$x_1^{e_1}\cdots x_i^{e_i}\cdots x_n^{e_n}-x_1^{e_1}\cdots x_i^{e_i-1}\cdots x_n^{e_n}=(x_i^2-x_i)x_1^{e_1}\cdots x_i^{e_i-2}\cdots x_n^{e_n}.$$

To start with, you need some assumption on the degrees of the $f_i$. For example, if $f_1 = x_1^{d}-2$, then although $\{f_1, x_1^2 - x_1\}$ is unsatisfiable, we already have $deg f_1 = d$, which we could choose to be $\gg n$ (where $n$ is the number of variables; in particular, in this case we have just one variable but can choose $d$ as large as we like).
In the papers you mention in the OQ, and in many settings in (algebraic) proof complexity, the $f_i$ are translations of Boolean clauses, so they are multilinear (and often even constant-degree). In this setting, there is a "standard" "truth-table" proof of degree $n$ based on the polynomial identity $\sum_{S \subseteq [n]} \left(\prod_{i \in S} x_i\right)\left( \prod_{i \notin S} (1-x_i)\right) = 1$. See for example Pitassi '96 (DIMACS).
